# В каком порядке выполняются уровни TCP/IP?

Tags: tcp-ip, osi

Пару дней назад встала задача узнать, что такое http протокол, но я решил начать сначала и приобрести базовые знания, где он обитает и вот коснулся TCP/IP...
Поправьте меня пожалуйста в моей абстракции клиент -> сервер:

1. Прикладной уровень - формирует поток информации (HTTP / FTP)
   *Вот здесь первый разрыв шаблона, т.к. тут должен быть интерфейс сокетов, которые уже предположительно должны общаться: принимать/отправлять данные, но как это возможно, когда еще не прошли остальные уровни? + Еще я прочитал, что socket = IP + PORT и это совсем выбило, т.к. IP будет доступен только на 3уровне. Ну хорошо, далее*
2. Транспортный уровень - разбивает собранную информацию на сегменты, добавляет свой хедер(в том числе порты). (TCP)
3. Сетевой уровень - добавляет свой хедер (dst_ip, src_ip) // то есть вот тут мы можем только говорить о адресате(в моем понимании)
4. Канальный уровень - формирует фрейм и (представим, что сервер и клиент в разных локальных сетях) также инкапсулирует все данные, добавляет свой заголовок(mac_src, mac_dst). То есть все это уходит на шлюз по умолчанию и так далее.

**Что не понятно**:

1. Исходя из моей абстракции у меня получается, что основная передача всегда идет по MAC адресам и передаются именно фреймы(т.к. все остальное инкапсулировано), но как тогда маршрутизатор будет решать куда отправить фрейм дальше, имея только МАК адрес? Ну отправит он его на свой шлюз по умолчанию, а тот что? Правильно ли я понимаю, что все маршрутизаторы сначала все это декапсулируют до транспортного уровня?
2. Как эти сокеты вписываются в эту картину? И что все-таки эти сокеты такое(IP + PORT(L2+L3) или Отдельный интерфейс между уровнем приложения и транспортным, и если это так, то они тоже инкапсулируются?)

Пару дней назад ничего про это не знал. Сейчас есть представление всего по отдельности, но не могу связать в одну картину. Везде информация именно по частным. Вот, спасибо всем, кто откликнется.

Comment: На первом уровне http-библиотеки, а не сокеты, так что рвать шаблон не надо

Comment: Маршрутизаторы (роутеры) умеют работать с IP-адресами (и зачастую даже с TCP/UDP), а устройства, которые не умеют, именуются коммутаторами (свитчами)

Comment: Каждый уровень - это дополнительные байты, в которые "заворачивается" пакет. Обычно эти уровни изучают просто для понимания сети. Практически красиво говорить о пакетах можно только с опорой на конкретный массив байт - тогда можно нарисовать что есть что. Практически - обычному пользователю такие данные не нужны.

Comment: *куда отправить фрейм дальше* - поищите в источниках - там есть адресат - поле получатель.

Comment: 1. Таблицы маршрутизации.
2. Сокеты отлично сюда вписываются. Сокет в сети - есть конкретный адрес вида 192.168.0.1:80  (например)

Comment: @nick_n_a Устанавливал, смотрел, я и говорю, что нет проблем с пониманием отдельных уровней, не складывается общая картинка. Почему, например, Вы говорите, что передаются пакеты, хотя последний этап - фреймы. Ну так в конце и полетят байты хедера фрейма + дата + кэш сумма. Пазл от этого все равно не складывается в голове

Comment: То есть, грубо говоря, маршрутизаторам нет смысла декапсулировать информацию, они просто умеют работать с IP и TCP портом? Нет смысла пытаться это понять, они их просто видят? И далее сверяют с таблицей маршрутизации и решают куда эти фреймы(или пакеты, хотя почему пакеты) отправлять?

Comment: Какую конкретно задачу вы преследуете?

Comment: @nick_n_a нужно понять http протокол для работы с fetch и тп. Но я залез сюда из-за интереса, информация в голове есть, не могу ее сгруппировать.

Comment: Если вопрос "Какая связь между IP и MAC" то... Кажется ответ на ваш вопрос - роутер знает, ориентируется (собирает базу - таблицу маршрутизации) по ARP протоколу https://habr.com/ru/post/326574/

Comment: @nick_n_a да, на этот вопрос я не знал ответа тоже. Хорошо, но а где тут фигурирует интерфейс сокетов?

Comment: @nick_n_a Изучил, в точку, я не знал протокол ARP, именно поэтому возник первый вопрос. Осталось разобраться с сокетами.

Comment: Что вам не понятно с сокетами?

Comment: Спасибо за прекрасный вопрос. К сожалению, развёрнутый ответ занял бы слишком много места, поэтому рекомендую почитать "Компьютерные сети" Олиферов в части IP. Их можно найти в сканированном виде, издание роли не играет. А сокеты — это программная абстракция для связи приложения с системой, и они бывают разные: IP-сокеты (в т.ч. TCP- и UDP-сокеты); raw-сокеты; IPX-сокеты и т.д. и т.д. См. также `man 2 socket`.

Answer (score -1, accepted):

Существует таблица OSI протоколов http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A1%D0%B5%D1%82%D0%B5%D0%B2%D0%B0%D1%8F_%D0%BC%D0%BE%D0%B4%D0%B5%D0%BB%D1%8C_OSI

Разберем её сверху-вниз.
7 - прикладной уровень (HTTP). HTTP содержит поля, которые позволяют сделать "валидацию" пакета, одно из них Content-Length (не всегда), например, отвечает за то, что пакет целый. Если пакеты все не получены - то приложение знает что пакет битый, и чаще всего битые пакеты не пропускает. Ещё важная функция HTTP протокола в том, что HTTP-пакеты отправляясь по сокету, могут быть разбиты на несколько частей, и именно HTTP протокол может гарантировать что пакет не битый и полный.

4 Дальше HTTP пакет передается через сокет библиотеку. Сокет формирует TCP пакеты. У этого вида пакетов есть "особенность" - нумерация. Длинный пакет разбивается на несколько мелких, и потом пакет собирается обратно. этот механизм обеспечивает библиотека сокета. Но библиотека не проверяет полностью пришел пакет или частично. Вариант что пол-пакета пришло сейчас, а пол-пакета через 5 секунд - норма. Теперь в пакет добавлен порт и контрольная сумма. TCP гарантирует что пакет не битый, но не гарантирует что пакет полный. Детальнее про TCP http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/Transmission_Control_Protocol (P.S. WS WebSocket сюда не относится, он выше даного уровня, его тоже в 7-ку)

3 Сетевой уровень. К TCP пакету добавляется одна из IP обверток (IPv4 или IPv6) и передается.. на уровень 2.

2 К пакету подшивается МАС и другая информация, потом пакет отправляется либо компу либо комутатору.

Теперь о маршрутизаторах (коммутаторах).

1. хабы (L1) - просто повторяют пакеты всем. Ориентируются только на длинну пакета и номер кабеля отправителя (давно не изготавливаются, сегодня большая редкость).
2. неуправляемый комутатор  (свич, L2) - повторяют пакеты сначала всем, потом прослеживают на каком кабеле активен мак, и отправляют пакеты конкретному маку на кабель. Ориентируются только по MAC
3. управляемый комутатор (свич, L3 комутатор, разг. циско) - может иметь свой ip может не иметь, чаще программируемый, умеет разбирать tcp/ip пакеты. Ориентируясь на маску подсети распределяет пакет в одном из направлений. Понимает ARP протокол, с помощью него корректирует таблицы маков близ-находящихся компов. Ориентируются как по МАС так и по IP.

Думаю интересен вопрос - а как же интернет - если вы отправляете пакет на 123.45.67.89 например, то ваш пакет может пройти и сотню коммутаторов. Первые будут все маски кроме локальных (10.х.х.х и 192.168.х.х 172.16.x.x ссылка часные IP) футболить на кабель провайдеру. Провайдер по первым двум-трем цифррам определяет допустим направление, и отправляет по новому маку - в направление, за тем вырисовывается страна, потом уточняется район, и так далее (при этом вскрывается уровень 3 что б определить IP). Сколько комутаторов проходит пакет - на практике не извесно, поскольку комутаторы блокируют попытки их обнаружить, да и их к-во на один и тот же ip может быть разное. Упустил, в интернете нет адресов 10.х.х.х и определенные программы (прокси) меняют IP адрес на  на интернетовский (чаще всего это делает сам провайдер). В интернете передача данных идет по-общим (не локальным) адресам.

На низком уровне соответствие МАС и IP назначается с использованием ARP-протокола. Прямо каждому IP присваивать соответсвие МАС - не нужно, для этого используются маски-подсети. Роутеры хранят по одной паре МАС-IP только близкорасположеных компьютеров, остальное - по маскам.

- Хорошая статья на хабре http://habr.com/ru/post/326574
- Часные IP http://ru.wikipedia.org/wiki/%D0%A7%D0%B0%D1%81%D1%82%D0%BD%D1%8B%D0%B9_IP-%D0%B0%D0%B4%D1%80%D0%B5%D1%81

Comment: Благодарю, ценю Вашу помощь, все постепенно проясняется. В голову залетел вопрос по мере чтения, чисто "любопытственный". "...ваш пакет может пройти и сотню коммутаторов...", значит ли это, что мой пакет могут перехватить? Или коммутаторы будут выбраны только "провайдерские"?

Comment: Видел спец-программы для предприятий, следящие за сотрудниками. Следить может сетевое оборудывание, и wifi (их владельцы) тоже, поэтому не рекомендуют секретничать в бесплатных wifi. А так обычный человек без спец-связей не перехватит пакет на коммутаторе провайдера. Да, комутаторы с той стороны будут провайдерские. До провайдера - могут быть условно-доступные.

Comment: свич (switch) и коммутатор - это одно и то же, только на разных языках, 1-е на английском, 2-е на русском. Просто коммутаторы бывают обычные и 3-го уровня (он же L3 switch), вот и все дела.

Comment: Часть "Теперь о роутерах" откровенно вводит читателя в заблуждение: 0) Роутеры — это вообще не свитчи. А свитчи - не роутеры. Хотя роутеры часто имеют свитчи в своём составе, а некоторые свитчи немного умеют в роутинг. 1) Хабы не существуют. Уже лет двадцать. 3) Управляемый коммутатор — это довольно редко L3. Чаще L2. Разница принципиальная. Суть управляемого коммутатора не объяснена, увы, никак. Никакие определённые программы не добавляют допполя в протокол. Поля в протокол добавляет IETF. В общем, каша, извините.

Comment: @AlexanderProkoshev напишите о них правильно. В интернете сведений много, но полную понятную картину описать тяжело.

Comment: @nick_n_a согласен насчёт "тяжело описать". Даже не то чтобы тяжело, там всё довольно просто, но требует почти несокращаемого переписывания ста страниц из Олиферов. Кста, очень их рекомендую всегда и всем в качестве полного и понятного описания того, "как работает Интернет".